# In search for a replacement for w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, html

Is there a library for Java that replaces the org.w3c.dom.Node with some better Node implementation?

I's so sick of the bad implementation of the whole default HTML parsing in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML parsing, I'd suggest [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.
>
> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to
>   the same DOM as modern browsers do.

Comment: Hmm, this seems promising. Do you have any info on how this compares to [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) ?

Comment: Nope, but afaik jsoup is like the de-facto standard for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html).
I use XPath with the help of [this article](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/04/xpath-over-html-using-jericho-and-jaxen.html) and [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/index.html)

I'm just not sure if this is the best way...